# How to assign File path to image src

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I written a src path as follow but why its not Displaying images

```
 <img src="/App_Data/imagesuplode/{{ee.U_pic}}" class="img-thumbnail" />
```

if the folder is Outside the App_Data its working file but why its not working when its under app_Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure about the path? if is the error 404 it is because the path... try getting the path through browser,

< localhost >/App_data/image......jpg

like

http://localhost:123/App_Data/imagesuplode/image.jpg

Comment: so, open the site... localhost/App_data/imagesuplode/c436edab-1f71-43c9-ac61-ab3a4127‌​b52c.jpg

Comment: imagesuplode? or imagesupload? try accessing
localhost:11900/App_data/ 
... follow the way and post here the entire path

Comment: Right click on the image in Solution Explorer. Click Properties and set its build action as Content. if it is already marked, change the 'Copy to output directory' to 'Copy always'